# Reflexive verbs

Tags: reflexive

I am totally confused about the reflexive verbs.
I am A2 student and just learning reflexive verbs.
I am confused very much with this.

The problem is I can not find any trustworthy site to get correct info or I don't even know what they are talking about .

I have read that  there are three category of German reflexive  verbs.

#### First.

True ones which do not have any meaning without the *sich* pronoun and they are compulsory.

#### Second.

Weak reflexive verbs which may be or may not be used with the *sich* pronoun. Can give same meanings.

#### Third.

Those weak reflexive verbs that make completely different meanings when used with the *sich* pronoun and without the *sich* pronoun.

That's all I know.
Now the problem is I can not find any good site the gives this all reflexive verbs according this categories and even though I have found some of them,the problem is I am confused whether they are correct or not as some true verbs that they provided me even were used without *sich*.

For example:

> Wir bedanken uns für ihr Vertrauen.

In site  http://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/bewerben+f%C3%BCr[enter link description here](http://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/bewerben+f%C3%BCr) there are a lot of examples that *bewerben* is not taking the *sich* pronoun.
And some sites say *bewerben für* is true while some say *bewerben um* is true.

And next problem is: how can I know when to use reflexive in cases like:

> Ich kaufe mir eine Pizza für meinen Freund.
>
> Ich kaufe eine Pizza für meinen Freund.

Is there any perfect way to use those reflexives that don't always tell the meaning of for themselves in German?
Like:

> Ich habe mich über ihn beim Lehrer beschwert.
>
> Ich habe über ihn beim Lehrer beklagt.

Which one should I prefer and does use of *sich beschweren* give any different sense?

Totally confused!

Where am I wrong? Please help me!

Comment: I tried to answer this question but it turned out to be too complex. Please be more specific what your problem is.

Comment: Maybe a proper grammar textbook could help you better.

Comment: A good dictionary will tell you if a verb is reflexive, either explicitly or by showing the verb preceded by "sich".

Answer (score 2):

As Janka pointed out in a comment, your question is rather complex.

Still, perhaps you will profit from some partial answers to sub-topics. Here is an answer regarding the use of ***sich bewerben***

*Sich bewerben* is always used with reflexive pronoun:

> Ich will mich bewerben
>
> Er bewirbt sich um eine Stelle / auf eine Stelle
>
> Er bewirbt sich für einen Job
>
> Wer sich nicht bewirbt, wird auch nicht zum Vorstellungsgespräch eingeladen
>
> Bewirb dich mal, vielleicht nehmen sie dich ja.

You cannot use *bewerben* without reflexive pronoun. (One exception see below)

*Sich bewerben* occurs with variuos prepositions. Both *um* or *für* are  possible. It depends on the object. There is no "rule" you can use to specifiy which preposition to use in what situation. You just have to get used to the usual usage.

- sich auf eine Stelle bewerben
- sich um eine Stelle bewerben
- sich um die Nachfolge im Amt des Parteivorsitzenden bewerben
- sich als Mechaniker bewerben
- sich als Mechaniker auf die Stelle als Betriebsleiter bewerben

---

Special case:

> Die Agentur schlug vor, den neuen Orangensaft mit Außenreklame zu bewerben.

Here you have *bewerben* without reflexive pronoun. But this is a completely different word *bewerben*, namely "Werbung machen für etwas" (promoting something, running an advertising campaign for something). In a good dictionarly this "bewerben" should be listed as a separate lemma.

---

#### Other issues

Your various sample sentences have quite some problems. Here are well-formed ones:

> Ich kaufe mir eine Pizza für meinen Freund.

Okay, that's a possible sentence. But it is very unusual. You would say this only in very specific situations. Your usual sentence would be:

> Ich kaufe eine Pizza für meinen Freund.
>
> Ich kaufe mir eine Pizza.

Your *Ich habe mich über ihm mit Lehrer beschwert* is a complete mess. Possible versions are

> Ich habe mich bei ihm über den Lehrer beschwert/beklagt
>
> Ich habe mich mit ihm beim Lehrer beschwert/beklagt
>
> Ich habe mich mit ihm beim Direktor über den Lehrer beschwert/beklagt
>
> Ich habe mich über den Lehrer beschwert/beklagt
>
> Ich habe mich beim Rektor über den Lehrer beschwert/beklagt.
>
> Ich habe mich mit meinem Freund beim Lehrer über den Rektor beschwert.

Note that these are very complicated constructs. I am not sure if at level A2 you really have to know to create such sentences correctly.

Note:

- *sich beschweren über* --> topic or object of the complaint
- *sich beschweren bei* --> to whom you complain; who listens to your complaint
- *sich beschweren mit* --> who is with you at the moment of complaint
- *sich beschweren wegen* --> topic of the complaint

> Ich beschwere mich **mit** meinem Freund **beim** Rektor **über** den Lehrer **wegen** dessen fieser Notengebung.

---

Special case:

Similar to the *bewerben* case, there is - as RHa correctly points out in the comments - also a verb *beschweren* that is used without reflexive pronoun:

> Du solltest den Sonnenschirm noch etwas beschweren, damit der Wind ihn nicht umbläst.

This *etwas beschweren* is best to be seen as a separate word. Meaning is: to put physical weight onto something.

Comment: The only compulsory reflexive examples which came to my mind are *sich freuen* and *sich schämen*. They make no sense otherwise.

Comment: If you want to use *beschweren* with the meaning of *to complain* reflexivity is mandatory. Otherwise the meaning is very different.

Comment: but could you tell me how can I find out whether it is etwas or not as etwas can be any situation or any object and how do I tell the difference between them. When beschwere is used and if their is any situation that someone  is complaining about that can also be we etwas,isnt it? And we just have to find out it's meaning from situation or is thier any fixed info about what etwas represents when using beschweren or any reflexive whose meaning changes with etwas .       If you get anyproblem in the way I am thinking please suggest me . What's the problem.